# Custom app distribution through Apple Business Manager

Tags: developer-program, apple-business

How can we distribute custom apps worldwide using redemption codes through Apple Business Manager?

Comment: Have you read the voluminous documentation Apple provides online on Apple Business manager? You need to do this and then ask *specific* questions. As it stands your question is a bit general and more likely the subject an editor might assign to one of his writers as a series of articles on this subject.

Comment: @SteveChambers normally I’m all about RTFM but this is quite confusing for many developers in my experience. Especially with the big transition from VPP to ABM and ABM changing monthly how it works for businesses.

Comment: Roger that! No ego here, just a supposedly educated opinion. Ready and willing to be corrected at any time, thx! @bmike

Comment: Also, any question, even a terrible one can become great if the right answer comes along. (Neither is the case here imo @SteveChambers) your comment was helpful and constructive and correct.

Comment: @SteveChambers its quite confusing in the apple docs. i had a conversation with apple team and for redemption codes to work in all regions one business must have registered in those countries(should have DUNS number).

Answer (score 1):

All apps on the general App Store are also available on Apple Business Manager, you upload to the App Store or test flight. If that works, you’re done - congratulations selling your app to businesses.

When you set pricing, you can optionally choose educational or volume pricing that is different than the general store.

Then, your customers use Apple Business or Volume Purchase Program to buy your apps.

- https://developer.apple.com/support/volume-purchase-and-custom-apps/

Read the portion about private apps if that’s your end goal.

> 1. From the App Store Connect Homepage, click My Apps, and select your app from the list.
> 2. Under Pricing and Availability, go to the Distribution for Business and Education section.
> 3. Select “Available on the App Store, for volume purchasing on Apple Business Manager, and for volume purchasing at a reduced price on Apple School Manager”.

Again, you just upload the apps, then set pricing and discounts when the app is approved for sale but before you make it generally available. The people buying have to sign up for VPP or ABM and then tell you their ID for private label apps. Or ask your prospective clients to do this one thing:

> Provide your developer with either the Organization ID from Apple Business Manager or the Managed Apple ID of your administrator.

Your is you in this case and you would set custom pricing and availability for their account.